# Bootstrap Accordion - Adding and removing parent

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, parent

I have a Bootstrap accordion with about 10 panels.  I have a checkbox that needs to accomplish the following:

unchecked - all panels get closed and only one panel is shown at a time (ie: a parent is defined so that when one panel opens the other one closes)

checked - all panels get opened and act independently (ie: no parent is defined)

The documentation doesn't cover such a scenario and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  I've tried the following (using the accordion example shown in the Bootstrap documentation as my HTML code) ...

Code that runs when the checkbox gets unchecked:

```
$(".collapse").collapse({ parent: "#accordion", toggle: false }, "hide");
```

Code the runs when the checkbox gets checked:

```
$(".collapse").collapse({ toggle: false }, "show");
```

However this doesn't seem to work at all.  For example when running the second code to show all the panels nothing changes.  I seem to be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by toggling the `data-parent` attribute on the `a` that does the collapse/expand with jQuery. Add something like this (assuming the ID of your checkbox is `allowmulti`):

```
$('#allowmulti').click(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $('#accordion a').removeAttr('data-parent');
  } else {
    $('#accordion a').attr('data-parent', '#accordion');
  }
});
```

Example [Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/NRpCQAnCKJ)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work 100% ... try the following on your Bootply example ... click on all three panels (to show them), then click the checkmark ... you'll notice that even though the data-parent attribute has been removed, the panels still behave as though the parent attribute hasn't been removed.

Comment: Any solution for this ? `$('#accordion a').removeAttr('data-parent');` removes the `data-parent` attribute but the accordion still behaves like it exists - doesn't switch to multi-open.